# PHP - create date range array with values from multi array key search

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have multi array created from previous search. Point of this is enable hotel reservation in case hotel is full and quests must change room during stay. So array $freeRooms is created as array of free room by dates.

```
$freeRooms = array(
0 => array
    (
        '2020-07-23' => 37
    ),

1 => array
    (
        '2020-07-20' => 38,
        '2020-07-21' => 38,
        '2020-07-22' => 38
    ),

2 => array
    (
        '2020-07-25' => 38,
        '2020-07-26' => 38
    ),

2 => array
    (
        '2020-07-20' => 59,
        '2020-07-21' => 59
    ),

3 => array
    (
        '2020-07-20' => 86,
        '2020-07-21' => 86
    ),

4 => array
    (
        '2020-07-20' => 39,
        '2020-07-21' => 39
    ),

5 => array
    (
        '2020-07-25' => 39,
        '2020-07-26' => 39
    ),

6 => array
    (
        '2020-07-20' => 40
    ),

7 => array
    (
        '2020-07-24' => 40,
        '2020-07-25' => 40,
        '2020-07-26' => 40
    ),

8 => array
    (
        '2020-07-20' => 41,
        '2020-07-21' => 41,
        '2020-07-22' => 41,
        '2020-07-23' => 41
    ));
```

Second array is date range:

```
$dateRange = array(0 => '2020-07-20',
1 => '2020-07-21',
2 => '2020-07-22',
3 => '2020-07-23',
4 => '2020-07-24',
5 => '2020-07-25',
6 => '2020-07-26');
```

I need create some final array for every day from $dateRange use some rooms from $freeRooms. Point is to use as minimal id rooms as possible to get something like this:

```
$finalArray = array('2020-07-20' => 41,
'2020-07-21' => 41,
'2020-07-22' => 41,
'2020-07-23' => 41,
'2020-07-24' => 40,
'2020-07-25' => 40,
'2020-07-26' => 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my actual solution:

1. order by count of free days

   array_multisort(array_map('count', $freeRooms), SORT_DESC, $freeRooms);
2. set $dateRange keys same as values

   $newRange = array_combine($dateRange, $dateRange);
   $finalRms = array();
3. loop and create new array

   foreach($ffa as $k => $v) {
   foreach($newRange as $nk => $nv) {
   if(array_key_exists($nk, $v) && array_key_exists($nk, $finalRms) == false) {
   $finalRms[$nk] = $v[$nk];
   }
   }
   }